# I want to learn more about Android camera. can anyone please suggest me a camera app source code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I learn some basic about camera app and I want to learn more about Android camera. I need an camera app source code. camera app contains some features like front and back camera both have flash light we can take picture as well as video and touch to focus. So anyone please suggest me a custom camera app. I search on Google and GitHub and I don't find any good camera app. I also try some GitHub projects but the project is not opening on Android studio.

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android studio already provides samples of helpful code that you can download them as project. And this is not restricted to just camera samples.

> File -> New -> Import Sample

[image]

- [Camera API doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera)
- [A good tutorial to start](https://demonuts.com/android-custom-camera/)
- [Helpful Repository](https://github.com/mitchtabian/TabianCustomCamera)

Comment: Thank you for answering me. But I want learn about some features like (switch to front and back camera ... Both front and back camera have flash .... Touch to focus)

Comment: Welcome; I guess that each feature can be searched and tested individually; kind of no single resource will get you helped .. good luck in this

Comment: @user12003759 .. this may be a good start https://demonuts.com/android-custom-camera/

Comment: this may also a good course; but unfortunately not free https://codingwithmitch.com/courses/android-custom-camera/... I have taken some other courses for Mitch on Pluralsight , he is a good instructor

Comment: and this is the full code of the above mentioned course https://github.com/mitchtabian/TabianCustomCamera ...

Comment: Yes bro I also follow him and I also have her some project source code like Instagram clone (https://github.com/mitchtabian/Android-Instagram-Clone?files=1?) In this project he also share camera part on Instagram clone. But the problem is project contains some other features like post a pic like comment and I am not sure which activity and fragment I use for separate camera app for me.